# Assign Role to User in Seed (laravel 8) (no packages)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

im trying to generate Users in Seeder but have no idea how i can assign role to them.

```
public function run()
{
    for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $userData[] = [
            'name' => Str::random(10),
            'email' => Str::random(10).'@gmail.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password')

        ];
    }

    foreach ($userData as $user) {
        User::create($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: which roles do you have?

Comment: "admin","author","read"

Comment: And you wanna assing random roles to users?

Comment: yes, sir. attach role to user in the seeder

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all, that was said, I suppose you wanna create random users with random roles. I think you use such a structure for roles - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many, so your code will be like:

```
public function run()
{
    $roles = [1,2,3]; //here you need to add id roles from the DB
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => Str::random(10),
            'email' => Str::random(10).'@gmail.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password')
        ]);

        // first variant
        $user->roles()->attach($roles[array_rand($roles)]) // attach random role to user, the can be duplicated
        //second variant
        $user->roles()->attach($roles[$i % count($a);]) // attach random role to user, the will be duplicated, if you have more users than roles 
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the effort. im bad at debugging. It doesnt work when i seed: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Comment: please attach error logs from `storage/logs/laravel.log` to your topic